# Setting up bridged networking between Linux host and Windows guest

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, bridge

I have a locked down version of Linux where tools like `virt-manager`, `virt-install` are not available.

`qemu-kvm`, `bridge`, `ip`, `brctl` commands are available though, and I have managed to run a`VM` running `Windows 10`. However, by default, it uses `NAT networking` and hence does not get onto the host network.

Unlike in `Fedora` or `CentOS`, to which I am used, where one can copy the `icfg-eth<n>` files to create the bridge, no such implementation is present on this version. However, bit-by-bit, I have managed to come close to creating a bridged network.

I used the following commands -

```
 ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root 

  ip link set tap0 up

  ip link add br0 type bridge

  ip link set tap0 master br0

  ip link set eth0 master br0

  ip addr add <my ip>  dev br0

  ip link set br0 up
```

to create the bridge, and enslave the `tap` and `eth` to it, and gave it an `ip`. Doing a`ip addr show`, I can see `br0` is up, and has the `ip` (same `ip` of the `eth0`). I cannot ping or tunnel into the host system though...If I set `eth0` to `nomaster` and then again set master to `br0` I am able to ping and tunnel into it, before it gets cut off again. Setting `br0` as master for `eth0` just cuts everything off. Even if I set an `ip` for `br0`.

I now want to start my VM and have this `br0` specified as its network. Unfortunately I am unable to do that as yet.

This guide here, https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#Public_Bridge goes on about creating the tap within a script, but didn't mention the last step of actually adding the ip to the bridge and enabling it, before starting the vm, also, when I do it this  way, there are some other complications, like tap device being specified as busy etc.

Another guide here, https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/HelperNetworking talks about using the bridge helper, but not sure how to invoke the `qemu` command after. I did add `allow br0` to `bridge.conf` to a newly created `qemu` folder with `/etc/` as suggested, but my hope that somehow this will be picked up automatically by the `VM` were not fulfilled.

Essentially, I have  -

1. eth0 connection enslaved to br0
2. tap enslaved to br0
3. eth0 status UP
4. tap0 state DOWN (not sure why, I did `ip link set tap0 up` but didn't work)
5. IP address given to br0
6. Host system not pingable, and cannot be SSH'ed into

I'd just like to specify this bridge device, `br0`, to my `VM` which I start as,

`qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3G --enable-kvm "VM.qcow2"`.

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. eth0 connection enslaved to br0

If I understand correctly from [this](https://fedoramagazine.org/build-network-bridge-fedora) link, the above step is not necessary since eth0 is already on a physical network

> has the ip (same ip of the eth0)

Also, the IP of eth0 and tap0 must be different since they are essentially logically separate NICs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated as per comments